# Import XML file with OpenXML vs SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there a benefit in using SSIS to import a 20MB XML file into a SQL Server DB vs importing the data with OpenXML directly from sql?

Comment: OpenXML won't import a file, so there's that.  You'd need to import the file into SQL Server somehow before using OpenXML.

Comment: Additionally, `OPENXML()`, and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument/sp_xml_removedocument` is a proprietary Microsoft API. It is currently kept just for backward 
compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards it supports w3c's XQuery.